# spring-security-oauth2 authorization endpoint gets blocked by authorizationserver

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have done quiet a lot of research and debugging but I cannot figure out the following behaviour that breaks my authorization endpoint...

I created a simple authorizationserver configuration like the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(4)
public class OpenIdConnectConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(ContextPaths.LOGIN,
                     ContextPaths.AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT,
                     ContextPaths.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
                     SamlRedirectContextPaths.SAML_CONSUMER_URL,
                     SamlRedirectContextPaths.USER_REDIRECT_ENDPOINT)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage(ContextPaths.LOGIN + "?npa");
  }

  /**
   * authorization server configuration for Open ID Connect
   */
  @Configuration
  @EnableAuthorizationServer
  protected static class AuthorisationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
  {
    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception
    {
      super.configure(security);
      security.sslOnly();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception
    {
      super.configure(clients);
      clients.withClientDetails(customClientDetails);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception
    {
      endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(new CustomInMemoryAuthCodeService(cacheManager));
      endpoints.tokenStore(new CustomTokenStore(cacheManager));
      endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", ContextPaths.AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT);
      endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", ContextPaths.TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

with this configuration everything works fine, can get my authorization code and my access token with the authorization code. BUT if I now enable the resource-server my application breaks with the new filter added into the security-filter-chain and I cannot figure out what the problem is.

my resource-server configuration looks as follows:

```
  @EnableResourceServer
  @Order(5)
  @Configuration
  protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter
  {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
      http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/oic/user-info")
          .authenticated();
    }
  }
```

with this I can execute the authentication mechanism for the user without problems but the case is then that the AuthorizationEndpoint gets an AnonymousAuthenticationToken. I am putting the logged in user manually into the spring security context with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If I then do some debugging in the "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint"

I can see that my CustomAuthentication is no longer within this security context. It got deleted and was replaced with the AnonymousAuthenticationToken. Anyone with an idea why this authenticationObject is overridden if I enable the resource-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found the solution. The ResourceServerConfiguration needs an additional entry:

```
/**
 * the resource server configuration for the user-info endpoint
 */
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
  http.sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(ContextPaths.USER_INFO_ENDPOINT)
      .authenticated();
}
```

this does the trick